# Passing a rendered Django page into a Wordpress frame

Tags: django, wordpress, templates

I have a client who has an already-completed wordpress site, and they want to add osqa.net into the site.  I'm the Django dev on the project, and I'm a little behind on my wordpress.

Is there a way to embed another web application's content into a wordpress page's content?

Should I just be doing this with an iframe?  I would have to pass parameters from the wordpress url into the iframe url.

**edit:**  Ideally anything in the url after /questions (like parameters and paths) would be passed onto a django application.  The django application would render a response, wordpress would take that response and include it in it's page.  Are there wordpress plugins that already exist like this?

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to hack OSQA to hide extraneous HTML and return only the pieces you want to include. That seems like a lot of effort for minimal benefits. I'd use an `iframe`.